# Java kernel cannot connect to the jupyter notebook

Tags: java, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to use java in jupyter notebook using SpencerPark IJava.

After the successful installations I opened a new java notebook but it is not connecting with the jupyter notebook.

I tried running this command given on the official docs of SpencerPark IJava in anaconda prompt

```
jupyter console --kernel=java
```

and it is throwing this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: io/github/spencerpark/ijava/IJava : Unsupported major.minor version 53.0
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
```

the same error is showing in jupyter notebook running server.

Anyone knows how to resolve this?

Comment: No, my kernel is not starting here, my java codes are running properly in other idles. So this solution is not helping.

Comment: You seem to misunderstand the error. The code was compiled with a more recent JDK version than the JRE trying to run it, hence the `UnsupportedClassVersionError`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IJava is compiled for java 9 (as this is the version that introduces JShell). This means the kernel needs to run on a JVM that is version 9 or higher. That is what the `Unsupported major.minor version 53.0` is suggesting.

Typically users that run into this problem have installed a correct version but they have an older JVM that is being used instead of their newly installed one. There are 2 options to fix this:

1. Tell Jupyter exactly what version of java to start the kernel with by changing the `kernel.json`:

   - Execute `jupyter kernelspec list` to find the install directory of the kernel.

     ```
     Available kernels:
       java           C:\Users\Spencer\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\kernels\java
       ...
     ```
   - In that directory find `kernel.json` and change `argv`. The `kernel.json` is a configuration file that also tells jupyter how to start the kernel. The `argv` is simply a command to execute. **NOTE:** use `/` or when using `\` you must escape them in JSON by writing `\\` instead.

     ```json
     {
         "argv": [
             // "java",
             "C:/absolute/path/to/jdk-9/bin/java"
             "-jar",
             "C:/Users/Spencer/AppData/Roaming/jupyter/kernels/java/ijava-1.3.0.jar",
             "{connection_file}"
         ],
         ...
     }
     ```

     I will also mention here, `env` is a dictionary of environment variables that Jupyter will set before calling the `argv`. You can use this to set `JAVA_HOME` or other variables that you always want set when running the kernel. On Mac this seems to be what users are more familiar with.

     ```json
     {
         ...
         "env": {
             "JAVA_HOME": "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.jdk/Contents/Home"
         }
     }
     ```
   - Optionally, you may want to also change the `display_name` to include the version. This is handy if you have a few versions setup so when you use the dropdown to pick a new kernel it will say `Java 9` (for example).
2. Add java 9 temporarily to your path before starting the notebook.

   - Like mentioned above the kernel just executes the `java` command to start up the kernel. This means that we can stick the more recent java version at the front of your path.
   - `set PATH=C:\absolute\path\to\jdk-9\bin\;%PATH%` will do this.

     - As a side note I have some variables `JAVA7_HOME`, `JAVA8_HOME`, `JAVA9_HOME` to simplify this switch. Then I use `set PATH=%JAVA9_HOME%\bin\;%PATH%` to use a certain version.
   - Then when using `where java` it may give multiple paths but the one at the top of the list should be java 9.
   - Finally launch the notebook with this new path and you should be good to go. Putting everything together

     ```
     set PATH=%JAVA9_HOME%\bin\;%PATH% && jupyter notebook
     ```

     or

     ```sh
     export PATH=$JAVA9_HOME/bin/:$PATH && jupyter notebook
     ```

Comment: Hey @SpencerPark , could this be the cause for this problem also? -->  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74674688/google-colab-notebook-using-ijava-stuck-at-connecting-after-installation-ref/74709951